# Strange compile errors in equality: (No method 'equals(Any?): Boolean' available)

Tags: types, kotlin, equality

The following code

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = listOf('A', Pair('X', 'Y')) 

    println(a[0] == 'B')
}
```

throws compile errors:

```
Error:(4, 17) Unresolved reference: ==
Error:(4, 17) No method 'equals(Any?): Boolean' available
```

as in the screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Why do these compile errors occur?

**EDIT 1**: It seems it is not related with a when expression.

**EDIT 2**: [Code snippet (Press the "run" button on the top right to compile)](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/m92i7snkf8btjo5n85d042dlru/1l64jk2h0ku4lkv6apan6id5n8)
I need to cast manually to avoid the compile error. Using a smart cast also does not work. (Or `val a: List<Any> = listOf('A', Pair('X', 'Y'))` works)

Comment: How is your project configured? Is the Kotlin standard library correctly attached to it?

Comment: @yole This is done in http://try.kotlinlang.org/ JVM env., Kotlin v.1.2.71

Comment: Kotlin sees your list as `List<Serializable>`

Comment: As @forpas mentioned problem is `Serializable` does not contain `equals` operator. If you create your list explicitly with `listOf<Any>( ... )`, or inverse your condition `'B' == a[0]` the problem doesn't happen.

Comment: @Pawel Isn't a `Serializable` a subtype of `Any`?

Comment: @Naetmul `Serializable` is an interface so it has no supertypes.

Comment: @Pawel I think the main curiosity (at least as I see it, but I think this is probably what Naetmul is also wondering about) is why the smart cast doesn't work. Why does `if (a[0] is Char) { println(a[0] == 'A') }` give a compiler error but `println((a[0] as Char) == 'A')` works fine? Isn't the smart cast in the first case meant to make it unnecessary to cast as in the second case?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou it does seem odd, one issue is querying a[0] twice doesn't let smart cast work, but even when I put local variable `val b = a[0]` and checked it didn't work. I guess smart cast only goes for subtypes, since it's still looking for `Serializable` equals method. You'd need to look at official forums to see if someone knows why it doesn't use `Any` equals operator.

Comment: the strange thing is: listOf('A', Pair('X', 'Y'))  is implicitely cast to List<Serializable> which gives the described error, but if you specifiy it explicitely listOf<Serializable>('A', Pair('X', 'Y')) it works :D. Looks like a bug to me

Comment: @WilliMentzel `listOf<Serializable>('A', Pair('X', 'Y'))` gives `Cannot access 'Serializable': it is internal in 'kotlin.io'`

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky case.

The highest common denominator between `Char` and `Pair` happen to be the `Serializable` interface, which doesn't define an `equals()` method. `listOf(...)` default type is defined as the highest common denominator of its elements.

Casting the array to List will allow using the `equals()` function implemented on `Any`, hence let the code work:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val a = listOf('A', Pair('X', 'Y')) as List<Any>

  println(a[0] == 'B')
  println(a[0] == Pair('X', 'Y'))

  if (a[0] is Char) {
    println(a[0] == 'A')
  }

  println((a[0] as Char) == 'A')
}
```

A bit more elegant would be to define the `Any` type specifically:

`val a = listOf<Any>('A', Pair('X', 'Y'))`

Comment: `Pair` does implement `Serializable`, but `Char`? Also isn't it that *the highest common denominator* should be used?

Comment: In Char, it is implicit, probably for cross-platform needs. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53033094/3834036; 
Right - will correct to highest common denominator :-)

Answer (score 1):

As it was pointed out in the comments and by Lior Bar-On's answer, the inferred type for `val a = listOf('A', Pair('X', 'Y'))` is `List<Serializable>`.

The strange thing is that if you let Kotlin infer the type, you cannot compile:

```
val a = listOf('A', Pair('X', 'Y')) 
println(a[0] == 'B')
```

but if you specify the type explicitely:

```
val a = listOf<Serializable>('A', Pair('X', 'Y'))
```

it will. This will not work in the Kotlin playground ([try.kotlinlang.org](http://try.kotlinlang.org)) giving:

> Error: Cannot access 'Serializable': it is internal in 'kotlin.io'

but if you compile it locally. This should be filed as bug.