# How comes kotlin.Char is Serializable? (it is not explicitly defined)

Tags: kotlin

`kotlin.Char` is defined in the following way:

```
public class Char private constructor() : Comparable<Char> {
...
}
```

Where `Comparable<T>` is defined as:

```
public interface Comparable<in T> {
    public operator fun compareTo(other: T): Int
}
```

So how comes a Char is `Serializable`?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  println('A'::class) // class kotlin.Char
  println('A'::class.java) // char
  println('A' is java.io.Serializable) // true
}
```

- Is it something added on compilation to Byte code?
- Is it documented anywhere?

Answer (score 4):

The basic types such as `Int`, `Double`, `Char`, etc. are represented on the JVM in one of two ways ([documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#representation)):

- whenever possible, as primitives (`int`, `double`, `char`),
- when required to be nullable or when used as generic type parameters, as the respective wrapper classes (`Integer`, `Double`, `Character`).

Both of these representations are serializable. Primitive types are serializable by default as they are, and their wrappers all implement `Serializable` as well, for example, as you can see in the documentation of [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html).

This sort of mapping between Kotlin and Java types is also mentioned [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types) in the Java interop documentation.

So the question is, why don't the Kotlin representations have `Serializable` as a supertype on the source code level? My guess is so that they're kept platform independent, as having them explicitly implement `java.io.Serializable` would make them depend directly on a JVM type.