# Why is Kotlin double equals not finding a .equals method?

Tags: kotlin, spring-batch

The below kotlin code does not compile. It claims *No method 'equals(Any?): Boolean' available*

```
override fun afterJob(jobExecution: JobExecution) {
            if (jobExecution.exitStatus == ExitStatus.COMPLETED) {
               //do stuff
            }
}
```

ExitStatus (a java class from spring batch) does have an equals method. See here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/ExitStatus.html

```
public class ExitStatus
extends java.lang.Object
implements java.io.Serializable, java.lang.Comparable<ExitStatus>
```

If I change == to .equals it works. Why is that?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53030524/strange-compile-errors-in-equality-no-method-equalsany-boolean-available ?

Comment: Nope. That one was about type inference for lists. There is no lists or type inference going on in  my question

Answer (score 0):

That is because when kotlin sees operator `==`, it only looks for `.equals(other: Any?): Boolean` method, not any other overloads. If the type does not have precisely this overload, it will not be found when using the `==` operator. Your type seems to have some other overload, something like`.equals(other: ExitStatus)`, which is used when you call it explicitly.

[More on Kotlin operator overloading.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html)

Comment: it has the regular equals https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/ExitStatus.html#equals-java.lang.Object-

Comment: Yes it does, but that is still not `.equals(other: Any?): Boolean`, so it does not participate in any way when you use operator `==`.

Comment: @MadKarel any class in Kotlin has `equals(other: Any?): Boolean` method inherited from `Any`

Comment: Object in Java maps to any in kotlin so the signature should be considered to be effectively the same